# how to suspend the other threads when one thread is wishing to execute or print something?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, sockets

i am new to **multithreading** in C(LINUX)

i am doing a **`multiple client server(single)`** program ,here i am using **`threads`** for   execution of the server,so i need when a client is waiting for reply other threads(other server threads) should not run,

```
        while(n = read(conn->sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer))  > 0 )
        {
            //HERE I NEED THE LOCK THE OTHER THREADS FROM THEIR EXECUTION

                    //process
                    //process
                    //end of process

            //HERE I NEED TO RELEASE LOCK FOR THE OTHER THREADS EXECUTION



        }
    }
```

i did not find anything specific on the net,even some example URL will be helpful

Comment: Why? Presumably this is the only thread handling this socket. It will block in `send()` if it has to, and it doesn't appear to be doing anything else that requires locking of global resources. `buffer` can be a local variable for example.

Comment: Oh by the way, your condition in the `while` loop is wrong, the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is higher for the `>` operator, so what you are doing is assigning to `n` the result of the comparison, and use that for condition.

Comment: Why the unconditional `break`? It makes the loop useless and it would skip the unlocking.

Comment: yeah correct , i noticed and i forgot to change ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Mutual Exclusion (mutex).  If you're on Windows I would use EnterCriticalSection on a critical section object.

You can also use `std::mutex`, which has been added in C++11 to try and create a standardized technique for this sort of thing.

Basically you have the thread that needs to transmit or access something take 'ownership' of the mutex and all other threads would check before taking action to see if the mutex is already owned.  If the mutex is owned the other threads would wait until it is released thus waiting their turn to take action.

**It is highly advisable to use the operating system built-in method for doing this like my suggestion for Windows.  If you don't, you will not have the same level of fairness.  Most operating systems have built in optimizations for this while the STL objects *may* not.**

Edit:
I some how missed the Linux tag but AlexBG provided the link to POSIX built in mutex usage: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables

Comment: You do know that the C++11 thread-classes (including mutexes and condition variables) will most likely use the platform native functions?

Comment: This is true, but not guaranteed.  And in this case the critical section objects are actually faster in terms of implementation due to the fact that they're targeted at this exactly problem.  They will automatically wait, etc providing a very clean interface for thread scheduling.

Comment: and here is my doubt,which thread will after the realease of lock(mutex),is it the thread which firstly found the mutex is currently in lock or a random one(thread) will run

Comment: Windows has very efficient thread fair-time management (probably the best) and will not let one thread have priority on the locks.  But you cannot force an order for the threads without queuing them somehow (which will require you doing some additional work to manage the execution orders)

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use e.g. [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), where you can [notify all waiting threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all).

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditions variables from POSIX pthreads if you need pure C.
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables

Comment: Thanks Alex, this complements the Windows example;  @siva This should be used for OS using POSIX threads, ie Unix (which includes Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Search for thread synchronization.
global variables will be shared by threads so use a global variable and then can acquire lock using that variable.

Comment: for two clients global variables would be good , but for more than two,we cannot predict which client will run after the lock released(I THINK)

Comment: but i think we can implement like binary semaphores to acquire exclusive lock right? and what you want is like mutually exclusive lock right?

Comment: the question is not something which would require a semaphore. he seems to want first in first out scheduling of threads waiting for the mutex.  Without forcing this yourself, however, it is up to the OS how it will happen

Answer (score 0):

To protect the concurrent access to a shared resource a simple (fast) mutex would do.

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

[...]


void some_func(void)
{
  [...]

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  /* Access to shared resource here (print to stdout for example). */

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  [...]
}
```

Please note that this code lacks error checking for the sake of readability.